"Ce faire" versus "Faire cela"
La phrase

Newton était un génie. Ses ouvrages font cela manifeste.

est elle remplaçable par

Newton était un génie. Ses ouvrages ce font manifeste.

? L'emploi du "ce" est-il correct ?
Je me suis demandé ceci après avoir constaté l'équivalence, du moins syntactique, de "pour faire cela" et "pour ce faire".

La première phrase n'est pas correcte. On dirait plutôt: Ses ouvrages le manifestent ou bien Ses ouvrages rendent cela manifeste, ou bien encore: Ses ouvrages le rendent manifeste. Mais faire cela manifeste n'est pas correct.
La deuxième phrase n'est pas correcte non plus: faire manifeste n'est toujours pas correct, et l'utilisation de ce n'est pas possible ici. Il faudrait dire: rendent cela manifeste, sans possibilité de remplacer cela par ce.
Il faut noter que faire cela est une expression "complète", qu'on ne peut pas supplémenter pour signifier faire quelque chose: faire cela beau, faire cela acceptable, faire cela léger, ..., faire cela manifeste sont toutes des expressions incorrectes. A la place de faire, il faut utiliser rendre ou bien utiliser une autre expression.
Il faut aussi noter quelques expressions toutes faites, telles que (dans un registre familier):

ça me fait froid dans le dos


ça me fait chaud au coeur


ça me fait tout drôle


ça me rend tout chose


Un commentaire : il faut utiliser rendre et non faire pour les adjectifs, et manifeste est un adjectif. Pour les noms, on peut utiliser faire; par exemple: "Cela me fait peur."

@PeterShor Mais: cela me fait chaud au coeur.

@PeterShor Also: ça me fait tout drôle, et ça me rend tout chose.

"Chaud" peut être une forme ancienne synonyme de "chaleur". Italien : fa caldo, espagnol : hace calor.

@LucaT.Castrillón Tout à fait possible, mais je ne suis pas un spécialiste :-)

En complément de la réponse de Frank, pour ce faire est bien un équivalent de pour faire cela (pour faire ça), mais c'est une expression figée et soutenue. Impossible donc d'en extrapoler des variations.

Je plussoie :-)

Même pas en français ancien ?

@LucaT.Castrillón Il existe d'autres expressions figées similaires, la plus proche étant ce faisant pour dire en faisant cela. Ce que je veux dire est que l'on ne peut pas "inventer" de nouvelles expressions figées à partir de celles qui existent.

@LucaT.Castrillón Attention, l' "ancien français" est une langue qui existait officiellement vers le 14e siècle si je ne me trompe, et 6 siècles plus tôt, c'est quand même très loin.

@LucaT.Castrillón De 750 à 1400 environ (https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancien_fran%C3%A7ais), ce qui veut dire bien difficile à lire/comprendre en 2024.

@Frank Ça dépend de pour qui. Les langues anciennes étaient souvent plus libres d'irrégularités, ce qui les rapproche du langage machine, l'idéal de compréhensibilité.

@LucaT.Castrillón Langage machine? Lequel? Assembleur? Micro-code? Ces langages sont surtout compréhensibles pour ... les machines ;-)

@LucaT.Castrillón J'ai peur que tu idéalises trop les langues anciennes :-) Les règles découlent des langues, pas l'inverse !

@jlliagre belle réflexion. Quand-même les langues s'usent avec le temps et de nouvelles inconsistances apparaissent.

@LucaT.Castrillón et d'autres disparaissent, sinon, nous parlerions des langues infiniment complexes.
